# OneSignal.setSubscription(true) not working on Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

When a user uninstalls the app, onesignal **Subscribed** status is changed to **No (Not Subscribed)**. When the user reinstalls the app, I can add and remove tags and change other info but I can't change the **Subscribed** status to **Yes**.

In the Application, I'm calling this method **OneSignal.setSubscription(true)** but It seems that it is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

   public void onCreate(){
       OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
       OneSignal.sendTag("tag", "change_tag"); // this is working
       OneSignal.setSubscription(true); // this is not working
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Somebody else seems to [have this problem](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/82)

Comment: Are you calling `setSubscription` with `false` at any point? I recommend contacting OneSignal support with your device's player / user id so they can check the status on their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually configuring wrong the **google project number** in gradle file. So it seems that OneSignal can add/remove tags without the google project number, but it can't subscribe the user (which makes sense).

```
manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                       onesignal_app_id: "88888888-88888-8888-8888-888888888888",
                       onesignal_google_project_number: "888888888888"]
```